# Firebase Firestore Bundle not working Flutter Web

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, bundle, flutter-web

Moin,

I am implementing for the first time Firestore bundles on Flutter Web.
It all works fine when I am running Flutter locally in the Chrome Emulator.
When I upload my project to the web like Firebase Hosting it fails.
I have a bundle created and hosted on Firebase Storage.

```
var buffer = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('exports/companyBundle.txt').getData();
// Load bundle into cache.
LoadBundleTask task = FirebaseFirestore.instance.loadBundle(buffer);
// Wait until all info has been loaded into cache!
await task.stream.last;
```

Looking in the console of the browser I got this:

@firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.10.0): SyncEngine Loading bundle failed with Invalid argument: 0

The bundle text file is loading fine from Firebase Storage and handed over to the loadBundle() function.
Once it gets to

```
await task.stream.last
```

it fails and gives the above error.

Normally once the bundle is loaded I would action the data but it won't even get this far.

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .namedQueryGet('latest-company',
            options: const GetOptions(source: Source.cache))
        .then((snaps) {
      for (var doc in snaps.docs) {
        Map dic = doc.data();
}});
```

As mentioned it runs fine in the emulator on my laptop but once deployed to the web it fails.

In my index.html I am using the libraries as per below.

```
  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <!-- If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
```

Follow by:

```
  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var firebaseConfig = {
      ...
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
    // workaround for case when adblock blocks firebase analytics
    if (!firebase.analytics || !navigator.cookieEnabled) {
      firebase.analytics = function () { };
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: You need to set up enabledPersistence as true.

Answer (score 0):

The scripts in the index.html file should be compared with the available libraries [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries).
The script tags that are included here do not include defer in the script tag and you may need that to fix your issue eg.

```
<script defer src=...>
```

Comment: I am not using any defer in my index.html